# Why do it succeed to deal with the memory size of long data type like this?

Tags: java, memory-management

I am new to dealing with very large integers in java, in regards to mathematical questions.

This is my answer to a solution of cutting papers into 1*1 squares.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long result = solve(841251657, 841251657);
    System.out.println(result);
}

static long solve(int n, int m) {
    long r = n*m - 1;
    return r;
}
```

The output is `1810315984`, which is far from the expected output of `707704350405245648`.

However, both ways below:

Either replacing the mathematical calculation for `long` with `BigInteger`,

```
static long solve(int n, int m) {
    BigInteger r = BigInteger.valueOf(n).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(m));
    return r.longValue() - 1;
}
```

Or inserting the input manually(not sure if it is the actual reason),

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    long m = in.nextLong();
    long n = in.nextLong();
    long cuts = m*n-1;
    System.out.println(cuts);
}
```

can both output the expected answer.

It would be really nice if I could know the reasons. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your method accepts `int`s and multiplies said `int`s. An `int` is a signed 32-bit number. It overflows.

Comment: Change `static long solve(int n, int m)` to `static long solve(long n, long m)`.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `n * m` is getting overflowed from `int` limit and therefore you can cast one of `n` or `m` to `long` in order to turn the result of the multiplication to `long`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long result = solve(841251657, 841251657);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    static long solve(int n, int m) {
        long r = (long)n * m - 1;
        return r;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
707704350405245648
```

It's important for you to know that when the value of an `int` overflows, it starts again from its minimum limit e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        System.out.println(x + 1);
        System.out.println(x + 2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
-2147483648
-2147483647
-2147483646
```